# Formatting IEEE Reference List

Tags: microsoft-word

[image]

**I keep running into this problem, and if I try to change things at the top, it just gets destroyed completely. Any advice or step by step is much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.**

**EDIT: After expanding the size from the right side.**

[image]

Comment: It would help if you told us what is wrong with it ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, thanks for your reply. Well, don't you see the reference numerics, they should be [1], [2], [3] etc. For some reason I cannot get this to work.

Comment: @DavidPostill I modified the text in the reference list from Justified to left. Still for a reason I cannot seem to understand, the problem remains. Does this have to do with page layout? Or?

Comment: Is it a table? It look like the first column is not wide enough ... The [1] etc is there, it's squashed up and vertical ...

Comment: @DavidPostill, yes, Word inserts the Reference as a Table. Not sure of why.

Comment: @DavidPostill, where do you mean?

Comment: Select the first table column and make it wider ...

Comment: @DavidPostill wait.

Comment: @DavidPostill, see my edit.

Comment: Well it's obvious you need to select the second table column and make it smaller.

Comment: How??? I have never had this problem before.

Comment: [Changing Column Width](http://wordribbon.tips.net/T009658_Changing_Column_Width.html)

Comment: [Resize a table, column, or row](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Resize-a-table-column-or-row-9340d478-21be-4392-81cf-488f7bbd6715)

Comment: @DavidPostill, as soon as I resizes the left-column it all gets screwed up.

Comment: <shrug> It is possible to get it right. Read the links carefully and keep trying :)

Comment: Column 1 (Left):
Height: 1,46 cm
Width: 0,47 cm

Column 2 (Right): 
Height: 1,46 cm
Width: 15,53 cm

Comment: If I modify the one on the Left, width: 0,49 cm it pushes the other column off the document page.

Comment: Don't use the Width field on the Table Tools > Layout tab. Instead, use the Column tab in the Table Properties dialog box to set a different width for the first column. The width of the second column should automatically adjust to compensate, and the right edge of the table shouldn't be pushed into the margin.